# How to check the digit that input the date in form dd-mm-yyyy in C?

Tags: c

Can we check the date input form dd-mm-yyyy and also check how many digits that users input? Example the users input 7-7-2000, is Invalid, it must be 07-07-2000.

This is my code.

```
int dateCheck(int argc, const char * argv[]){

int day;
int month;
int year;
int count = 0;
char inputValue[20];
printf("Enter date : ");
fgets(inputValue, sizeof(inputValue), stdin);
sscanf(inputValue, "%d-%d-%d",&day,&month,&year);

if ((year >= 1919) && (year <= 2119)) {

        if ((month >= 1) && (month <= 12)) {

            if ( ((day >= 1) && (day <= 31)) && ((month == 1) || (month == 3) || (month == 5) || (month == 7) || (month == 9) || (month == 11)) ) {
                printf("Valid.\n");
            }
            else if ( ((day >= 1) && (day <= 30)) && ((month == 4) || (month == 6) || (month == 8) || (month == 10) || (month == 12)) ){
                printf("Valid.\n");
            }
            else if ( ((day >= 1) && (day <= 28)) && (month == 2) ){
                printf("Valid.\n");
            }
            else if ( (day == 29) && (month == 2) && ( (year%400 == 0) || ((year%4 == 0) && (year%100 != 0)) ) ){
                printf("Valid.\n");
            }
            else{
                printf("Invalid.\n");
            }
        }
        else{
            printf("Invalid.\n");
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("Invalid.\n");
    }
```

Comment: Did you carefully read the documentation of [sscanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) (notably its `%n` and its return count)?

Comment: What's wrong with years less than 1919 or greater than 2119?

Comment: Also, I'd say 07-07-2000 isn't valid, either -- [it should really be 2000-07-07](https://xkcd.com/1179/).

Comment: @SteveSummit Before 1919: No decent C/C++ Compilers; After 2119: Don't care, I'll most likely have passed away by then! :-)

Comment: @SteveSummit Regarding 'best' date format: Isn't that up to the OP?

Answer (score 1):

> Can we check the date input form dd-mm-yyyy and also check how many digits that users input?

Sure, how about using some helper functions?

Divide the task in conceptual parts and write code for each. Divide and conquer.

```
// return 0: fail
// return 1: success
static int scan_int(int *dest, const char *s, int min, int max, int digits,
    char endchar) {
  *dest = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < digits; i++) {
    if (*s < '0' || *s > '9')
      return 0;
    *dest = *dest * 10 + *s - '0';
    s++;
  }
  return *dest >= min && *dest <= max && *s == endchar;
}

static int isleapyear(int year) {
  if (year % 4) return 0;
  if (year > 1582) {  // see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar
    if (year % 100 == 0 && year % 400) return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}

static int eom(int year, int month) {
  static char eoms[1 + 12] = {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
  if (month != 2) {
    return eoms[month];
  }
  return eoms[month] + isleapyear(year);
}
```

Now armed with some helper functions, the task is directly coded.

```
// dd-mm-yyyy
#define YEAR_MIN 1919
#define YEAR_MAX 2019
int dateCheck(void) {
  int day, month, year;
  char inputValue[20] = {0};
  printf("Enter date : ");
  fgets(inputValue, sizeof inputValue, stdin);

  if (scan_int(&year, &inputValue[3 + 3], YEAR_MIN, YEAR_MAX, 4, '\0')
      && scan_int(&month, &inputValue[3], 1, 12, 2, '-')
      && scan_int(&day, inputValue, 1, eom(year, month), 2, '-')) {
    printf("Valid. %02d-%02d-%04d\n", day, month, year);
    return 1;
  }
  printf("Invalid.\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Nifty trick:  Code validates `day` after fetching a valid `year, month`.

Comment: I'll take it as an "aye test!" (PS: I knew all along what you meant - just being pedantic!)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are prohibited from using the functions provided in `string.h`, they can make you date check a bit easier. For example, you can verify that only allowable characters are present in the input using `strchr()`. You can also use `strchr()` to locate each `'-'` when checking that each `dd mm yyyy` group is the correct number of characters. You can use `strlen()` to verify the final `yyyy` group is 4-characters, and you can use `strcspn()` to trim the trailing `'\n'` at the end of any input read using `fgets()`. The rest is simple ariithmetic.

For example, you could write a `chkdate(const char *s)` function to check that the string `s` is in your desired format, returning `1` if it is, or `0` otherwise, e.g.:

```
#define DATEGRP 3   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define DATELN 10
#define DATEC 128

/* check if given date format is dd-mm-yyyy
 * returns 1 on success, zero otherwise
 */
int chkdate (const char *s)
{
    const char *datechars = "-0123456789",  /* valid characters */
            *p = s,                         /* pointer & end-pointer */
            *ep = p;
    size_t  group = 0;                      /* group counter, dd mm yyyy */
    int groups[] = { 2, 2, 4 };             /* req'd chars per group */

    for (int i = 0; s[i]; i++)              /* verify only datechars in s */
        if (!strchr (datechars, s[i]))
            return 0;

    /* loop over dd mm groups using strchr to locate '-' */
    while (group < DATEGRP - 1 && (ep = strchr(p, *datechars))) {
        if ((ep - p) != groups[group])      /* verify correct no. of chars */
            return 0;
        p = ++ep;       /* update p to following char */
        group++;        /* increment groups counter */
    }
    /* check chars in final group and all digits */
    if (strlen (p) != (size_t)groups[group] || strchr (p, '-'))
        return 0;

    return 1;       /* if you made it here, valid date, return 1 */
}
```

You can also make a trivial solution using `sscanf` alone, that behaves in the exact same manner simply by using a proper *format string* with appropriate *field-width* modifiers on each integer conversion checking the return of `sscanf` against `3`, **except** the `sscanf` trivial solution will fail for any case where `yyyy` begins with an integer and then contains an invalid character) e.g.

```
int chkdate (const char *s)
{
    int d, m ,y;
    return sscanf (s, "%2d-%2d-%4d", &d, &m, &y) == 3;
}
```

Adding the required headers and a short example program that will validate user input using the function above you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DATEGRP 3   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define DATELN 10
#define DATEC 128

/* check if given date format is dd-mm-yyyy
 * returns 1 on success, zero otherwise
 */
int chkdate (const char *s)
{
    const char *datechars = "-0123456789",  /* valid characters */
            *p = s,                         /* pointer & end-pointer */
            *ep = p;
    size_t  group = 0;                      /* group counter, dd mm yyyy */
    int groups[] = { 2, 2, 4 };             /* req'd chars per group */

    for (int i = 0; s[i]; i++)              /* verify only datechars in s */
        if (!strchr (datechars, s[i]))
            return 0;

    /* loop over dd mm groups using strchr to locate '-' */
    while (group < DATEGRP - 1 && (ep = strchr(p, *datechars))) {
        if ((ep - p) != groups[group])      /* verify correct no. of chars */
            return 0;
        p = ++ep;       /* update p to following char */
        group++;        /* increment groups counter */
    }
    /* check chars in final group and all digits */
    if (strlen (p) != (size_t)groups[group] || strchr (p, '-'))
        return 0;

    return 1;       /* if you made it here, valid date, return 1 */
}

int main (void) {

    char buf[DATEC] = "";
    size_t len;

    fputs ("enter date (dd-mm-yyyy): ", stdout);    /* prompt */
    if (!fgets (buf, DATEC, stdin)) {               /* read/validate input */
        fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    buf[(len = strcspn(buf, "\n"))] = 0;    /* trim trailing '\n', save len */
    if (len != DATELN) {                    /* if not DATELN chars, invalid */
        fputs ("error: invalid date format,\n", stderr);
        return 1; 
    }

    if (chkdate (buf))  /* check dd-mm-yyyy format */
        puts ("date is valid");
    else    /* otherwise, invalid format */
        fputs ("date is invalid.\n", stderr);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Wrong number of digits:

```
$ ./bin/chkdate
enter date (dd-mm-yyyy): 7-7-2000
error: invalid date format,
```

Invalid character `'a'` included:

```
$ ./bin/chkdate
enter date (dd-mm-yyyy): 07-7a-2000
date is invalid.
```

Good date:

```
$ ./bin/chkdate
enter date (dd-mm-yyyy): 07-07-2000
date is valid
```

There are literally dozens of ways to approach this with many combinations of loops, counters, pointers, character classification, etc... There isn't any "right" way, so long as it is reasonably efficient and does the validation. So experiment, write it several different ways and choose the one that is most readable and understandable to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can first take in the string, check it's format and then extract individual digits from the string.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void checkDate(){
    char str[20];
    printf("%s","Enter date : ");
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
    //char str[11] = "32-02-2019";

    int d1=str[0]-48; //Convert the ascii digits to integers
    int d2=str[1]-48;
    int day=d1*10+d2;

    int m1=str[3]-48;
    int m2=str[4]-48;
    int month=m1*10+m2;

    int y1=str[6]-48;
    int y2=str[7]-48;
    int y3=str[8]-48;
    int y4=str[9]-48;
    int year=y1*1000+y2*100+y3*10+y4;

    int format_validity=0;
    printf("stringLen:%ld\n",strlen(str));
    if(strlen(str)==11){ //check length of the string
        if(str[2]=='-' && str[5]=='-'){ //check the separator positions
            if((d1>=0 && d1<=9) && (d2>=0 && d2<=9)){ //check digits are in range 0-9
                if((m1>=0 && m1<=9) && (m2>=0 && m2<=9)){ //check digits are in range 0-9
                    if((y1>=0 && y1<=9) && (y2>=0 && y2<=9) && (y3>=0 && y3<=9) && (y4>=0 && y4<=9)){ //check the digit are in range 0-9
                        format_validity=1; //mark the format valid
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }//else the format is invalid

    if(format_validity){
        //Your Code from here
        if ((year >= 1919) && (year <= 2119)) {
            if ((month >= 1) && (month <= 12)) {
                if (((day >= 1) && (day <= 31)) && ((month == 1) || (month == 3) || (month == 5) || (month == 7) || (month == 9) || (month == 11)) ) {
                    printf("Valid.\n");
                }
                else if ( ((day >= 1) && (day <= 30)) && ((month == 4) || (month == 6) || (month == 8) || (month == 10) || (month == 12)) ){
                    printf("Valid.\n");
                }
                else if ( ((day >= 1) && (day <= 28)) && (month == 2) ){
                    printf("Valid.\n");
                }
                else if ( (day == 29) && (month == 2) && ( (year%400 == 0) || ((year%4 == 0) && (year%100 != 0)) ) ){
                    printf("Valid.\n");
                }
                else{
                    printf("Invalid.\n");
                }
            }
            else{
                printf("Invalid.\n");
            }
        }
        else{
            printf("Invalid.\n");
        }
    }else printf("Invalid format.\n");
    printf("day:%d, month:%d, year:%d",d1*10+d2,m1*10+m2,year);
}


int main(){
    checkDate();
    return 0;
}
```

Test:
[1]

> Enter date : 29-02-2019
>   stringLen:11
>   Invalid.
>   day:29, month:2, year:2019

[2]

> Enter date : 29-02-2020
>   stringLen:11
>   Valid.
>   day:29, month:2, year:2020

[3]

> Enter date : a0-03-2020
>  
>   stringLen:11
>   Invalid format.
>  
>   day:490, month:3, year:2020

[4]

> Enter date : 12-2-2019
>   stringLen:10
>   Invalid format.
>   day:12, month:17, year:152